# How to check if my pickerDate is rotating or stopping in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I have a pickerDate, if I try save the date while this is rotating, my app crash. But if I wait for stop rotating picker, this save correctly.

I need check if my pickerDate is stop or rotating to save or wait for not get crash. Or stop this..  How can I do this?

```
 datePicker.addTarget(self, action: Selector("handleDatePicker:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)


  @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
var date = ""
var age: NSDate!

func handleDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
    age=sender.date
    date = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
}

func calculateAge (birthday: NSDate) -> NSInteger {

    var calendar : NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    var now: NSDate = NSDate()
    var dateComponentNow : NSDateComponents = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear, fromDate: birthday, toDate: now, options: nil)

    return dateComponentNow.year
}
 @IBAction func okButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    //code to calculate age and save this 
    var ageCalc = calculateAge(age) //Here crash
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please show the code that crashes, along with some context (what triggers the code, in what function is that code, and so on).

Comment: When do you read its value? What's the error message?
What do you use to read your value? What triggers the reading? Do you use `UIControlEventValueChanged`?

Comment: I have added my code, yes I use UIControlEvents.ValueChanged

Comment: What's the code of `calculateAge()` and the one of `handleDatePicker:`?

Comment: You might be having bug in your calculateAge() method. Check it by just commenting. Will you please provide the code from the above mentioned one.

Comment: But if the picker ins't rolling there isn't any problem whit calculate... I edit my question with the code, thanks

Comment: Do you have a date selected in picker while it's roling. Because may be it crash due to nil date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check whether the `(birthday: NSDate)` is available or not. Therefore just check for nil.

```
func calculateAge (birthday: NSDate) -> NSInteger {

    if (birthday != nil) {
        var calendar : NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        var now: NSDate = NSDate()
        var dateComponentNow : NSDateComponents = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear, fromDate: birthday, toDate: now, options: nil)
        return dateComponentNow.year
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Just check for `nil` date and if so return `-1` or `NSIntegerMax` to keep in track that you haven't calculated a right age yet.

**UPDATED:** `if (birthday != nil)` or use `if let` syntax to check for `nil` like

```
func calculateAge (birthday: NSDate!) -> NSInteger {

    if  let thisBirthday = birthday {
        var calendar : NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        var now: NSDate = NSDate()
        var dateComponentNow : NSDateComponents = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear, fromDate: thisBirthday, toDate: now, options: nil)
        return dateComponentNow.year
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: are you using beta 6? if birthday { does not conform 'BooleanType'.       (birthday: NSDate!) is corret, go to try this, thanks

Comment: @user3745888 you have to check for nil date just using any convenient method in Swift. Updated